# Ecryptfs unmounts ever half hour or so after home partition ran full

Tags: hard-drive, ecryptfs

A week ago, my home partition (encrypted with ecryptfs, set up in the install process) ran full. I've deleted some files, so now there is plenty of space again. But for some reason, the ecryptfs filesystem randomly unmounts.

If that happens, I just run `ecryptfs-mount-private`, enter my passphrase, and everything is fine again for some time, but then it unmounts again.

Any idea what could be wrong there and how to fix that?

Here are my `/var/log/syslog` lines for a timeframe within which the problem occurred:

```
Aug 26 16:35:01 jost-desktop CRON[3070]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Aug 26 16:38:58 jost-desktop systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Aug 26 16:38:58 jost-desktop colord[1378]: (colord:1378): Cd-WARNING **: failed to get session [pid 3135]: No such device or address
Aug 26 16:38:58 jost-desktop colord[1378]: message repeated 2 times: [ (colord:1378): Cd-WARNING **: failed to get session [pid 3135]: No such device or address]
Aug 26 16:39:01 jost-desktop CRON[3146]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean)
Aug 26 16:41:13 jost-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Aug 26 16:41:13 jost-desktop systemd-tmpfiles[3185]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
Aug 26 16:41:14 jost-desktop systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 26 16:45:01 jost-desktop CRON[3232]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Aug 26 16:51:58 jost-desktop systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Aug 26 16:51:58 jost-desktop colord[1378]: (colord:1378): Cd-WARNING **: failed to get session [pid 3301]: No such device or address
Aug 26 16:51:58 jost-desktop colord[1378]: message repeated 2 times: [ (colord:1378): Cd-WARNING **: failed to get session [pid 3301]: No such device or address]
Aug 26 16:55:01 jost-desktop CRON[3317]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

There is nothing related in `dmesg` (last entry is from the boot process).

**Update:** I've also checked the SMART status off all disks, and there don't seem to be any problems. Output from `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000DM003-1CH162
Serial Number:    S1D8W76M
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 05c382341
Firmware Version: CC46
User Capacity:    1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Sep 14 22:43:53 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  575) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 108) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   119   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       234006864
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2479
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   084   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       4621305762
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   081   081   000    Old_age   Always       -       16848
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2506
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       6 7 20
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   065   049   045    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 16/36)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       216
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3086
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   035   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (0 5 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       16941h+00m+06.008s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       51949642453
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       40959708870

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        82         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%        17         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         9         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```